# SVG Path attribute 'd' transition

Tags: animation, svg, path, transition

I have an SVG with multiple `<path></path>`.

I want to change the `d` attribute and apply a transition on this change.ù

I tried the usual way *(`transition: all 1s`)*, but it doesn't work.

Do you have an idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: you can't apply a CSS transition to an attribute, only to a CSS style.

Comment: Then do you know what I should do?

Comment: Animate the attribute using SMIL instead perhaps.

Comment: I will look into it, thanks. But it's a shame IE dosn't support it.

Comment: Use a polyfill for IE. https://leunen.me/fakesmile/

Comment: Transition work here, why? https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/NRwANp